# Getting an error on Close Date during lead conversion

Tags: lead-conversion

I'm very new to Salesforce so I may need lots of help. When converting a Lead to an Opportunity I am getting this error:

> Error: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, A workflow or
>   approval field update caused an error when saving this record. Contact
>   your administrator to resolve it. Close Date: value not of required
>   type: common.formula.FormulaEvaluationException: Month or Day out of
>   range in DATE() function: []
>   Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.handleOpportunityInserts: line 737,
>   column 1 Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.convertLead: line 104,
>   column 1

which I believe is just saying that the close date on the opportunity is incorrect so the opportunity cannot be saved. The main problem I'm having is that I can't figure out where the close date is being set during the conversion. Where is this being set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being caused by a workflow rule firing when the Opportunity is being created on Lead conversion.

If you have administrator privileges check on Opportunity to see if there are validation rules or triggers on it. You also need to check if any Workflow rules exist which are on Opportunity. The Workflow rule will show which object it is related to and if it is active.

If you are not the System Administrator then you would have to contact your organisation's Salesforce Administrator.

[image: Workflow Rules]

[image: Opportunity]

Comment: it looks like there are no validation rules and there is one trigger but it is fired after undelete or before delete so it wouldn't be fired during a conversion.

Comment: Ok, so are there any Workflow rules or Process Builder processes on Opportunity. The other thing to check for is Approval Processes on Opportunity.

Comment: Yes! There is a workflow rule on opportunity and I'm going to guess it's in the wrong format. Thank you!

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer as accepted as that will take it out of the unanswered questions view here. Thanks.